# Trying to reset 2 different ng-model on 2 different input file type in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular i'm trying to clear the model on click of cross image

```
    <div class="content">
    <div class="field">
    <label for="form-bridge-logo1">Logo 1</label>
    <input id="form-bridge-logo1"  type="text" value="" ng-model="myFile.name"         />
    <button class="clear-file" ng-if="myFile.name" ng-click="clear(myFile)"></button>
    <input type="file" id="browsefile" name="cover" file-browser="myFile" data-logo-type="primary" class="browse-file-input" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"/>
   <label for="browsefile" class="browse-btn">Browse</label>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field">
    <label for="form-bridge-logo2">Logo 2</label>
   <input id="form-bridge-logo2" type="text"  ng-model="myFile1.name"/>
   <button class="clear-file" ng-if="myFile1.name" ng-click="clear(myFile1)"></button>
 <input type="file" id="filebrowse" name="cover" file-browser="myFile1" data-logo-type="secondary" class="browse-file-input" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"/>
 <label for="filebrowse" class="browse-btn">Browse</label>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my js file.

```
$scope.clear = function(fileName) {
    if (fileName.name === $scope.myFile.name && $scope.myFile !== undefined) {
            $scope.myFile = $scope.initial;
        } else if (fileName.name === $scope.myFile1.name) {
            $scope.myFile1 = $scope.initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of condition in your clear function.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do that:

```
 <button class="clear-file" ng-if="myFile.YOURDATA" ng-click="myFile.YOURDATA=''">Clear</button>
```

So you don't need an extra function